# 301 redirect for a query string with space to a non dynamic URL

Tags: mod-rewrite, redirect, query-string

What is the best way to redirect a specific page that has a space in query string to a name page? I have tried the following which doesn't seem to work:

```
Redirect 301 "/user.php?name=user name" /users/list
```

Comment: use `+` or `%20` instead of space according to url encoding scheme

Comment: Neither Redirect nor RedirectMatch allow you to specify a query string for the redirect source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the discussion in comments, neither Redirect nor RedirectMatch allow us to specify a query string for the redirect source, like this:

```
Redirect 301 /user.php?name=user%20name /users/list  # this does not work!!!
```

We should deploy the powerful machine of RewriteEngine even for so little, in /.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} name=user%20name [NC]
RewriteRule ^user\.php /users/list [R=301,NE,L]
```